# In Google AppMaker, How to filter using a single DateBox?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to **filter** a table using a **DateBox**. The problem I have is that it doesn't display the records of that day when binding value is set to `@datasource.query.filters.date._equals`. However, it does work when the filter is `_greaterThanOrEquals`, but it also includes later records.

I am using SQL tables with date field type is `DATE`.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. We're looking into it.

For now please use workaround:
Remove the binding and set 2 filters in onValueEdit event with code like:

```
widget.datasource.query.filters.FIELD_NAME._greaterThanOrEquals = newValue;
widget.datasource.query.filters.FIELD_NAME._lessThanOrEquals = newValue ? new Date(newValue.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000) : null;
widget.datasource.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

bind DateBox value to

```
@datasource.query.filters.NameOfDateFiled._equals
```

and don't forget reload datasource in "onValueChange" event.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: It doesn't work unless a LessThan/GreaterThan/OrEquals is used.

Comment: just tried @datasource.query.filters.Date._lessThanOrEquals and it works, don't forget to readload datasource in "onValueChange" event.

Comment: That's what I am saying. It does work with _lessThanOrEquals  _greaterThanOrEquals, etc... However, not with _equals. I am reloading the datasource.